# Exclude a validated array object from inserting into db

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm trying to exclude an object from an array from inserting into a database only after validation. The code sample is below

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $request->merge([
        'added_by' => auth('api')->user()->id,
    ]);

    $travel = TravelSummary::create( $this->validateRequest($id = null) );

    event(new TravelRequestCreatedEvent($travel, $action = 'added travel request'));

    return (new TravelSummaryResource($travel))
                ->response()
                ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

Below is the array of validated fields

```
private function validateRequest($id){
    return request()->validate([
        'travel_request_no' => $id ? 'required' : 'required|unique:travel_summaries',
        'purpose' => 'required',
        'total' => 'nullable',
        'cash_advance' => 'nullable',
        'advance_amount' => 'nullable|lte:total',
        'added_by' => 'required'
    ]);
}
```

Can the **total** be excluded only after validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$data = $request->only(['travel_request_no', 'purpose', 'cash_advance', 'advance_amount', 'advance_amount']);
```

or

```
$data = $request->except(['total']);
```

after validation then pass that data to create model. here is an example.

```
$this->validateRequest($id = null);
$data = $request->only(['travel_request_no', 'purpose', 'cash_advance', 'advance_amount', 'advance_amount']);
//or you can use except
//$data = $request->except(['total']);
$travel = TravelSummary::create($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unset the data you wish to exclude, after validation, like so:

```
// The validator will return the validated data as an array
$data = $this->validateRequest($id = null);
// This will remove the key and value from the array.
unset($data['total']);

$travel = TravelSummary::create($data);
```